# SharePoint Online’s Block Download File Policy - Does it involve some user licensing?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document-library, administration, azure-ad

I have a requirement where they don't want users to download files.
There are 2 options I have been reading about.

- Using Conditional Access Policy
- Using a PowerShell command.

My question is there any user licenses required if I want to use the PowerShell command option?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online's Block Download File Policy requires a **Microsoft Syntex - SharePoint Advanced Management** license.

**Source**: [Block download policy for SharePoint sites and OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/block-download-from-sites)

You can read more about this feature and license requirements in below Microsoft official documentations:

1. [Block downloads for view-only files in SharePoint and OneDrive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/block-downloads-for-view-only-files-in-sharepoint-and-onedrive-6051184b-62ac-4149-b874-13dcd40ef91e)
2. [Block the download of Teams meeting recording files from SharePoint or OneDrive (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/block-download-meeting-recording)
3. [Microsoft Syntex - SharePoint Advanced Management overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/advanced-management)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh.I would read through the links

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Hi @naijacoder, does this help you in any way?

Comment: If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) & [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future. It also removes this question from "Unanswered Questions" list.